# Intel vtune takes lots of time to collect information

Tags: intel-vtune

When I am using vtune to collect information of a process I only need to focus on the result of one particular dll(lets say X.dll). But When I finished with running the process and in the collecting information stage, one dll(lets say Y.dll) will stuck with retrieving information forever.

I only have symbols for X.dll
I don`t have symbols for Y.dll

Is there a problem with symbol server settings ?.
I`m using Visual Studio 2008 and Win7 32bit.

Comment: I don't think this is about the debug symbols. What "Sample After" value are you using, and for how long do you collect the trace?